# imageresizer remote reader plugin only displays the remote image if no query strings are present in URL

Tags: imageresizer

I'm trying to resize/crop the images stored on one of our servers and use them on another, also our server. Image resizer is running on www.aapg.org. Remote images are stored on assets.aapg.org.

Not sure why it doesn't work. I followed the process outlined in http://imageresizing.net/plugins/remotereader -- everything looks OK. I tried both a signed remote URL and human-friendly syntax, and neither worked for me.

Here are the plugins from the Web.config file I'm using:

```
<add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
<add name="DiskCache" />
<add name="SeamCarving" />
<add name="SimpleFilters" />
<add name="PdfRenderer" downloadNativeDependencies="true" />
<add name="DropShadow" />
<add name="WhitespaceTrimmer" />
<add name="PrettyGifs" />
<add name="AnimatedGifs" />
<add name="WebPEncoder" />
<add name="WebPDecoder" />
<add name="RemoteReader" />
<add name="CloudFront" />
```

And the remote reader plugin configuration ('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is obviously not what I'm using):

```
<remotereader signingKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" allowAllSignedRequests="false" allowRedirects="5">
<allow domain="aapg.org" />
<allow domain="assets.aapg.org" />
</remotereader>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, what error message did you get?

Comment: There were no error messages. All it did was redirect me to the home page, instead of rendering a modified image.

Comment: That's not something ImageResizer does. You have other components or elements at work here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. Meanwhile, any ideas where I should start looking? What could cause this?

Comment: URL redirect/rewrite rules, 404 handlers, application error handlers. If there's an underlying problem, it's being masked by this home page redirect, and we need to stop that first.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start there.

Comment: We've removed the redirect which occurred on a 404 error. Now it simply throws a 404 error (still doesn't work). What would you recommend our next step to be?

Comment: Were you able to access `/resizer.debug.ashx`, the diagnostics page?

Comment: Got the page results, it's too long to post here. How do I show it to you?

Comment: Use [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com)

Comment: Thanks, here's the link: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ac5ce5c1aebb93d92f93

Comment: Can you provide an example of human-friendly syntax that didn't work?

Comment: http://staging.aapg.net/remote/store-assets.aapg.org/img/products/ST59_lg.jpg -- this link works without query strings. Adding query strings forces the redirect. Try it.

Comment: Definitely not ImageResizer behavior. Can you reproduce this in a clean, standalone webapp?

Comment: No, the clean app works. We have taken another look at our DNN setup and found a solution: in host settings we set regex not to redirect URLs containing "/remote/". That fixed it! Thanks for helping us through this issue!